# Magento: Sort product display images in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.9

I am uploading about 30 images for each product with numeric names like:

001.png
002.png
003.png ....

but after uploaded it showing on front end like

002.png
003.png
001.png ....

how could it be auto sort in front end following is the piece of code from Magento media.phtml

```
<ul class="product-image-thumbs">
        <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($_thumbWidth, $_thumbHeight); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach?>
        <?php if ($_360IsSet && !$_embedded):?>
            <?php $_360ViewWidth  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_360ViewWidth) ?>
            <?php $_360ViewHeight = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_360ViewHeight) ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('webrotate360/frame_' . $_viewerSkin . '.html') . '?iframe=true&width=' . $_360ViewWidth . '&height=' . $_360ViewHeight ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">
                    <img src="<?php echo $_360icon ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: there's no auto sort that I know of, it would probably be easier to modify `getGalleryImages` to get the order you need.

Comment: thanks @WhiteHat foir your response i have fixed this with jquery :)

Comment: Cool, will you post your answer? I and others would like to see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure @WhiteHat here is my code:

```
var mediaImages = [<?php $numItems = count($this->getGalleryImages());$i = 0;foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):?> <?php echo '"'?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(450, 450); if(++$i === $numItems) { echo '"';} else { echo '",';}?><?php endforeach?>];
var mediaImagesSorted = mediaImages.sort();
jQuery('.MediaDiv').html(mediaImagesSorted);
```